# Vuetify - make square v-card with centered text (both axis)

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I am trying to make a v-card that has card text centered right in the middle of the square. I tried using v-spacer and some other CSS classes that vuetify comes with, but unfortunately while text stays centered horizontally, I am having trouble making it also center vertically.

This code has almost everything working except the vertical centering of the middle text

```
  <v-container fluid>
    <v-row>
      <v-col cols="6" sm="4">
        <v-card rounded color="info">
          <v-responsive aspect-ratio="1">
            <v-card-title>
              Top left - correct
            </v-card-title>
            <v-card-text class="text-center white--text">
              middle center
            </v-card-text>
            <v-card-actions class="justify-center white--text">
              bottom center
            </v-card-actions>
          </v-responsive>
        </v-card>
      </v-col>
    </v-row>
  </v-container>
```

Here is a JS fiddle with example: https://jsfiddle.net/mrpquke4/3/

Try resizing the browser window with the example above and you will see v-card stays square shape while growing or shrinking(as desired), text stays centered horizontally (as desired), text is not centered vertically (the problem).

JSFiddle:

[image: JSFiddle]

Desired Result:

[image: Desired]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this css:

```
.v-responsive__content {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    // justify-content: center; // this will make everything vertical center
    justify-content: space-between
}


.v-responsive__content > div {
    width: 100%;
}
```

You can name space the class for any css conflict:

```
.my-card .v-responsive__content { ... }
```

Comment: This moved everything in the center. I need v-card-title (first line) and v-card-actions (last line) to stay top and bottom and center only v-card-text. here is your suggestion applied: https://jsfiddle.net/8wr1xjzf/

Comment: @luriG see if this works `justify-content: space-between`? if that's not helping you, call me on skype, let's fix it. Skype ID: syed_haroon

Comment: That did it @Syed! If you could update the answer with `justify-content: space-between` for anyone else that searches for this would be great. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `align-self` on `v-col` ( `align` on `v-row` if you want put in seperate rows)  for horizontal and `offset` on `v-col` for vertical

```
  <v-row>
    <v-col align-self="center" cols="6">
      <v-card class="pa-3">align : start</v-card>
    </v-col>

    <v-col align-self="center" cols="6" offset="3">
      <v-card class="pa-3 text-center">align : center</v-card>
    </v-col>

    <v-col align-self="end" cols="6" offset="6">
      <v-card class="pa-3 text-end">align : end</v-card>
    </v-col>
  </v-row>
```

Here is the updated jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/tunzLcw5/

Comment: That does not work: text is aligned top center not in the middle of the card. Add a height to the card and you will see text stays near top instead of being in the center of the card. Here is example: https://jsfiddle.net/p0zuv756/

Comment: put v-row v-col in your card, or use v-card-title and v-card-actions with  `class="justify-center"` https://jsfiddle.net/f7bck1go/

Comment: I see you added `style="height:200px"`, without it, text is not centered. Since aspect ratio of vcard is 1 in my example (square), it's height is changing according to the width of the page, so I cannot hardcode `style="height:200px"`. Do you know how to make it always centered when height is dynamic?

Comment: It should be `<v-card class="d-flex justify-center">`, not on the inner text item [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/helloworld/7xhq0Lfg/5/)